# Is it good practice to use protected method instead of create new virtual function for each derived class in inheritance tree. E.g. in descritption

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

For example i have three level inheritance tree and I need to implement virtual function in all levels. Which way is better?

```
class Base {
    public:
    void foo() {
       //do something
        dFoo();
    }
    private:
    virtual void dFoo() = 0;
}

class DBase: public Base {
    private:
    void dFoo() {
        //do something
        ddFoo()
    }
    virtual void ddFoo() = 0;
}

class DDBase(): public DBase {
    private:
    void ddFoo() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

or

```
class Base {
    public:
    virtual void dFoo() { foo(); }

    protected:
    void foo() { //do something }
}

clase DBase: public Base {
    public:
    virtual void dFoo() {
       Base::foo();
       foo(); 
    }

    protected:
    void foo() { //do something }
}

clase DDBase: public DBase {
    public:
    virtual void dFoo() {
        Base::foo();
        DBase::foo();
        foo(); 
    }

    protected:
    void foo() { //do something }
}
```

I would prefer second way, but I read that protected methods are bad practice.

Comment: Making a virtual function private is stupid. It prevents calling base functionality although base is inherited.

Comment: virtual private functions are not stupid.  see Herb Sutter's http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm

Comment: virtual functions that _require_ you to call the base virtual (as seems to be common practice in many java code-bases) IS stupid.

Comment: @tony in second way virtual function dont call the base virtual

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article [Virtuality by Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) that you may find instructive. It advises separating the public interface from behaviour that is implemented by derived classes (an implementation detail): make public functions non-virtual and virtual function non-public.

This design is used for [std::basic_streambuf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not about wich solution looks nicer. It's about the interface you want to define.

The first design might be more stable, beause of the non virtual interface(nvi).

If you limit the access to your virtual function (e.g by not making them public), it is easier to change the implementation without having every user to change its code and recompile.

(Herb sutter has a nice article about this topic: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base {
    public:
        void foo () {
            vfoo();}

    protected:
        virtual void vfoo() {
            // do something
            }};

class DBase : public Base {
    protected:
        virtual void vfoo () {
            Base::vfoo();
            // do something
            }};

class DDBase : public DBase {
    protected:
        virtual void vfoo () {
            DBase::vfoo();
            // do something
            }};

int main () {
    DDBase x;
    Base&  r = x;
    r.foo();
    return 0;}
```